# Exchange 2010 Online Archive Not Showing Up in Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I currently activated the Online Archive feature for Exchange 2010 but for some reason it won't show up for Exchange users using Outlook 2010 client.  If I log into OWA, it will appear there but not in Outlook 2010 client.  How exactly do you activate this feature to appear for Outlook client users?  I've read somewhere that you need a VLK version of Outlook 2010 and not a retail/OEM copy.  Is this true?

Can you guys recommend some troubleshooting steps on how to resolve this issue?  Autodiscovery is working fine to my current knowledge.

Thanks in advance,

-- UPDATE --
I found my answer to my problem.  The client PC isn't registered on Active Directory and also because Office Pro Plus isn't installed either.  I hope you guys find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

The solution we found was to edit the "Full Access Permission" on the affected mailbox, delete the "NT Authority\Self" entry, save that, then readd the same "SELF" entry and restart Outlook about 5 times.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Office Pro Plus or any special volume licensed edition.  You do need Outlook 2010 (or later) and a touch of patience.

After the mailbox is created, AND the Global Address List is update (nominally 1-24, but depends on your configuration) the archive mailbox will be available for the user.  It should appear automatically in Outlook, but the most sure fire way to see it is to close all Outlook windows and wait until there are no more active Outlook.exe processes in Task Manager (~2 minutes for me).  Then re-launch outlook.

During the Exchange Server discovery portion of Outlook's startup it will enumerate the available mailboxes (now including the Online Archive) and list them all in the client.

Again, this isn't dependent on a specific edition of Office/Outlook or on accessing from a domain joined PC.  But do remember that to be compliant with licensing you will need an Exchange Enterprise CAL for each user that has an Online Archive (or uses Retention Policies, or any of the other Enterprise level features).

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. The version of Outlook included with Office 2010/2013 standard does NOT support the Exchange online archive. You will need to install either a standalone version of Outlook by itself or install Outlook as part of a volume license version of Office Pro (note: retail versions of office pro also do not support it). Full details are here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/outlook-license-requirements-for-exchange-features-HA104047984.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rex, and I concede the point (the link tells all).  I do find it funny that that is 100% contrary to the educational materials MS uses for training where they state that it is an available feature which simply requires a license.